# Javascript: How to add an optional forward slash to a template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, cypress, template-literals

So I am trying to have two optional arguments and an optional forward slash. The reason I need an optional forward slash is because the base url is just `localhost:3000/web/reserve` not `localhost:3000/web/reserve/`. The default empty arguments are working as expected when passing nothing into `webpageCheck` however I can't get the optional (/) to work. If I did `http://localhost:3000/web/reserve/${label}${count}` it would fail when calling `webpageCheck` because there is no forward slash at the end. Does anyone know how to do this?

```js
const web = {
        label: 'Hello',
        count: '10',
    };
    
const webpageCheck = (label = '', count = '') => {
     const optionalSlash = '/'
      cy.url().should(
         'eq',
         `http://localhost:3000/web/reserve${optionalSlash + label}${optionalSlash + count}`
        );
    };
    
 webpageCheck()
```

Comment: While you could bake the logic you are describing into a template literal, it seems like it would be a lot easier to just use string concatenation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds like the `optionalSlash` should be in the string before `label` or `count`, and if `label` or `count` is missing, we skip adding the `optionalSlash` for that variable. If that's true, you could do a [simple ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#syntax) when constructing the string.

```js
http://localhost:3000/web/reserve${
  label ? optionalSlash + label : ''
  }${
  count ? optionalSlash + count : ''}`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can treat the arguments anonymously, allows any number of path segments

```js
const webpageCheck = (...args) => {
  const path = [...args].map(arg => `/${arg}`).join('')
  const expected = `http://localhost:3000/web/reserve${path}`
  cy.url().should('eq', expected)
}
```

If `label` resolves to `undefined` but `count` is present, that should probably count as an error

```js
const webpageCheck = (...args) => {
  const path = [...args].map(arg => `/${arg}`).join('')
  expect(path).not.to.include('undefined')

  const expected = `http://localhost:3000/web/reserve${path}`
  cy.url().should('eq', expected)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the parts in an array, filter it by boolean and join with wanted separator.

```js
const
    web = { label: 'Hello', count: '10' },
    webpageCheck = (label = '', count = '', separator = '/') => 
        ['http://localhost:3000/web/reserve', label, count]
            .filter(Boolean)
            .join(separator);

console.log(webpageCheck());
console.log(webpageCheck(web.label));
console.log(webpageCheck(web.label, web.count));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to define a string with your logic, something like this:

```
const web = {
        label: 'Hello',
        count: '10',
    };
    
const webpageCheck = (label = '', count = '') => {
     //Logic example
     let addressOptionsString=(label!==''? ("/" + label):'') + (count!==''? ("/" + count):'')
      cy.url().should(
         'eq',
         `http://localhost:3000/web/reserve${adressOptionsString}`
        );
    };
    
 webpageCheck()
```